# Create mst through clicking dialogues reponses

Tags: c#, vb.net, wix, windows-installer

I was wondering if any out there has created a mst response tool i.e clicking through the guid and capturing the properties they set?

I know there is a few solutions out there that do this like http://www.jontylovell.net/index.php?page=10 but I want to be able to do it silently or via a command line with not form pop ups for saving mst the only popups I want are for the msi. I think this was written in vb.. so either vb or c# would be great.

My question is how can I create a mst for a msi through clicking the dialogues and automatically generate the mst once all the dialogues have been clicked?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create mst response tool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36195973/create-mst-response-tool)

Comment: Nope this is not a duplicate the old post was deleted....